# PostrgreSQL count how many transactions in the last 7 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I'm a SQL noobie and have been working on this problem for hours on end.

I have a table of transactions and the field txnDate is of date data type. I've altered the table to add a column called txnLast7days which should count how many transactions exist in the table within the last 7 days of txnDate.

This is [my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJe6d.png)

What statement can I use to update all the table records at once and counts the # of transactions within a 7 day period based on txnDate and inserts the result in the txnLast7days column for each row?

This is the statement I'm currently using based on a suggestion, but I'm still not getting the right result.

```
UPDATE temp2
SET txnLast7Days = subquery.txnLast7Days
FROM
    (       
        SELECT  txnDate, sum(dateCounts.transactionCount) OVER (ORDER BY txnDate ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as txnLast7Days
        FROM (SELECT count(*) transactionCount, txnDate FROM temp2 GROUP BY txnDate) as dateCounts
    ) subquery
WHERE temp2.txnDate = subquery.txnDate
```

My current query is not updating the txnlast7days with the right count, as you can see here
[my current query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvjuC.png)

Comment: @AlonsoC-- Can you show your table or query or more detail ...

Comment: Please use Aliases

Comment: Clearly you haven't explained what you need well enough for our understanding. However, providing sample test data - as *text* not an image - and the exact expected output of that data would go a long way toward resolving this. And allow a valid answer to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get a count for each `txnDate` and then get the rolling 7 day count for each `txnDate`.

The former is done with a simple `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` on your table. The latter is done with a window function that looks back over the last 7 records, ordered by `txnDate`, and sums those counts up.

You can then use those results in an `UPDATE` query to populate your new column.

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET txnLast7Days = subquery.txnLast7Days
FROM
    (       
        SELECT  txnDate, sum(dateCounts.transactionCount) OVER (ORDER BY txnDate ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as txnLast7Days
        FROM (SELECT count(*) transactionCount, txnDate FROM yourtable GROUP BY txnDate) as dateCounts
    ) subquery
WHERE txnDate = subquery.txnDate
```

Comment: Hi I tried your query but I'm getting the following error ERROR:  column reference "txndate" is ambiguous LINE 9: WHERE txnDate = subquery.txnDate. This refers to the txndate in the WHERE clause

Comment: Try qualifying that thing then like: `WHERE yourtable.txnDate = subquery.txnDate` and see if that makes it happy.

Comment: Thanks, I did the change and now I get no errors. However the logic of the query is not right, because the result I'm getting in the txnlast7days field is just an ascending number for each row starting from 1. For example the first record shows 1, the second 2, etc. But I'll keep plugging at it :-)

Comment: Curious. Perhaps run out that SELECT statement and make sure it's producing reasonable amounts for each distinct `txnDate`. Something sounds screwy, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding your data.

Comment: Actually your last posted output is exactly what you are asking for. You have 5 days with 1 transaction per day. So for the 1st day you get 1, for the 2nd day 1 transaction for that day + 1 transaction for prior days; and so the same for each day 1 to 5. It's not the query that's bad it's the test data. If you have 1 transaction per day then total transactions will increment by 1 each day - just what you are getting. Suggestion, expand your test data to include at least 8 days; for some day have multiple transactions.